# Pre-loading dependent promises in Angular 1

Tags: angularjs

Bear with me as this is hard for me to wrap my head around. I have an object that we pull from a database that is mapped with numbers as keys:

```
entity: {
23: "This is a definition of the string here",
34: "This is a string definition for 34 here",
55: ['array', 'here'],
...
}
```

Let's imagine the "23" key refers to the name of the author and "34" refers to the name of the publisher and so on. I don't want to manually map out these relationships in each controller. As such, I would think that the best place to do the mapping is in a Service named something like "BookService".

I started by creating a bunch of functions in the BookService like:

```
vm.getAuthor = function () {
   return vm.entity[23];
}
...
```

Per this style guide (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), I tried to then do:

```
vm.getAuthor = getAuthor;

function getAuthor() { return vm.entity[23]; }
```

Is this the right way to approach this? The major problems I've run into are:

1. I get "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" errors. Based on what I've read on SO, not sure how I am supposed to move the definition out of the function?
2. I am resolving the "entity" attribute in the UI-router prior to the controller. However, the BookService doesn't get this until I pass it in. So, for each function, do I need to send in the entity attribute? For example, change the function to something like:

   ```
   function getAuthor(entity) { return entity[23]; }
   ```

I'm still a beginner with angular, so hopefully this makes sense. Let me know if it needs further clarification!

Comment: Did you set the entity on the `vm` pointer? I.e. `vm.entity = entity`?

Comment: Yes I've done this a couple of ways. Per question #2 above, I've tried to send it entity with each call, though that doesn't feel right. The other method is in the controller i have a setBook function that essentially sets the entity to vm.entity in BookService. That doesn't 'feel' right either though...

Comment: Please include the code for the router resolve function. It seems like the best approach is to call the BookService from the router resolve function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be better to create a factory that creates books from a supplied entity:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.factory('BookFactory', BookFactory);

BookFactory.inject = [];
function BookFactory() {

  function newBook(entity) {
    return {
      author: entity[23],
      publisher: entity[54],
    };
  }

  return {
    newBook: newBook
  }
}
```

This way if that mapping ever changes, you will only have to edit this one function.

In your controller you can create a new book object like this:

```
var myBook = BookFactory.newBook(entity);
console.log(myBook.author); // this will work
```

As far as your error, we would need to see a lot more info to understand why you are receiving that. It is a very vague error, and it is unlikely that how you structure your book object has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

### Pre-loading dependent promises in Angular 1

> not sure how I am supposed to move the definition out of the function?

To get something "out of a function", use a [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

In the case of the `.then` method of a promise, what one gets "out of the function" is a new promise that resolves to what is returned. One can thus [chain promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises):

```
  $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
       book: function($routeParams, BookService) {
           var bookId = $routeParams.bookId;
           var bookPromise = BookService.getBook(bookId);
           var finalPromise = bookPromise.then( function(book) {
               var authorPromise = BookService.getAuthor(book.authorId);
               var nestedPromise = authorPromise.then( function(author) {
                   book.author = author;
                   return book;
               });
               return nestedPromise;
           });
           return finalPromise;
       })
    }
  })
```

The resolve function does two service calls, the first looks up the book using the `bookID`, and the second looks up the author using the `authorId` returned by the first service call. The resolver adds the resolved `author` property to the `book` object. The chained promise resolves to the `book` object with its `author` property set to the author string.

> ### Chaining Promises
>
> Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.
>
> It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)